# use Google calendar javascript api directly after you have passed OAuth

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I'm using Google calendar Javascript api. The login is through Google OAuth. In the login consent screen, I've requested the user to give full calendar access. But after the user logged in, I still can't call `gapi.client.calendar.events.insert`, it gives errors says "require loggin".

Does that mean I still need to authorized again like in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js)?

Given the fact that the loggin already authorized app to access calendar, why can't I call calendar api directly?

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=loadCalendarApi"></script>

loadCalendarApi = function() {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', someCallback());
}

// if the user already logged in, I want to be able to call this function
function saveToCalendar() {
    gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
            'calendarId': 'primary',
            'resource':event
    });

    request.execute(someCallback());
});
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: One quick question, once the user logins, Did he authorized you to access his/her calendar? If you are using service account, did you do domain wide delegation? https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation, please describe your use case clearly.

Comment: @SGC The user is requested to give full access to his calendar when he firstly log into the app, the log is google Oauth, with a calendar scope. After he logs in, I wan to call "gapi.client.calendar.events.insert" directly, I don't use a service account.

Comment: When user logins to your app fro the first time, user should authorize your app then you can access the data depending on the scopes used. If you use access_type='offline', then from second login user is not prompted with consent screen. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer